# Colorbox fill all framesets

Tags: jquery, colorbox, frameset

I've been looking for a way to solve this problem but can't seem to find it...
I have the following index.html with this frameset:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link href="js/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script>
function MyCallForColorboxFunction(html){
    alert('done');
    $.colorbox({title:'Aniversariantes',inline:true, href:"#colorbox_content", width:"600px", height:"500px"});
}
</script>
</head>
<FRAMESET ROWS="100,70,*" FRAMEBORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="2">
<FRAME SRC="cre.html" NAME="superior" MARGINWIDTH="0" FRAMEBORDER="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" NORESIZE SCROLLING="NO">
<FRAME SRC="menu.html" NAME="menu" MARGINWIDTH="0" FRAMEBORDER="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" NORESIZE SCROLLING="NO">
<FRAME SRC="principal.html" NAME="corpo" MARGINWIDTH="0" FRAMEBORDER="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" NORESIZE SCROLLING="YES">
</FRAMESET>
<noframes>
<body>
    <div style="display:none">
      <div id="colorbox_content" style="padding:10px; background:#fff;">
        content here
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

What i'm trying to do is to open from "corpo" frame a colobox to fill all the 3 frames but it's filling only the "corpo", i've made a few tests and it seems I can execute functions on the index.html from "corpo" using for exemplo top.MyCallForColorboxFunction() but nothing happens not even an error, as if there is no  to display a colorbox.

Could anyone help?
Yours,
Diogo

Comment: Watch out with using framesets as they are not supported in HTML5.

Comment: I think you'll want to rethink using a frameset. As mentioned, it is not supported in HTML5 and a colorbox outside of the frame won't be possible. You can recreate this layout using fixed divs and overflow:scroll, and avoid these issues.